# How to get the size of HTTP Response?

Tags: go, size, response

I want to determine the size of the response. it's easy way to get the contentsize by resp.ContentLength. But, Size is the combined size of the response headers (usually a few hundred bytes) plus the response body, as delivered by the server.  how can I get the size of the response headers ? Or Is there anyway to get the size of the response directly?

Comment: FYI responses are often chunked, and don't have a Content-Length at all

Comment: There's no easy way to do it with net/http, but what use would the info be? It's likely not the exact transfer size, since the request may be TLS/HTTP2. You could approximate it with [httputil.DumpRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest)

Comment: Would checking from the receiving end of the connection satisfy your needs?

Comment: I think you could, in theory, implement an [`http.Transport`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) that wraps the built-in `net.Conn` with one that precisely counts bytes transferred. But [`httputil.DumpResponse`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpResponse) similar to what JimB's saying sounds much more practical.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an `http.ResponseWriter` that counts the bytes it writes.  It should be pretty simple to create your own, or you can use an existing library like [this one](https://github.com/miolini/datacounter).